# What is the correct way to use “respective”?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, difference, sentence-structure

If driver A drove car X only, and driver B drove car Y only, and driver C drove car Z only; and so on and so forth; then which of the below sentences is right (or any other sentence, but only below sentences are priority and preferred as I need to build further upon those sentences).

1. drivers drove their respective cars.
2. drivers drove respective cars.
3. respective drivers drove their respective cars.
4. respective drivers drove respective cars.
5. drivers drove cars respectively.
6. drivers drove their cars respectively.

Regards

Friendly Joee

Comment: The word "respectively" doesn't work in *any* of your examples (should be *They drove their **own** cars*). That's because "respectively" requires a context where the sequence of one "list" (of two or more elements) can be equated with the sequence of another *previously specified* list. For example, ***John and Jane drove the Ford and the Audi respectively***, which unambiguously asserts that the sequence of the list ***Ford, Audi*** can be "mapped" on a one-to-one basis with the list ***John, Jane*** (***Ford*** goes with ***John*** and  ***Audi*** goes with ***Jane***).

Comment: ...I would advise avoiding ***respective*** with anything like this sense. It's a [declining usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=respective%2Crespectively&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crespective%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crespectively%3B%2Cc0) anyway, and even when it *is* used it rarely adds anything significant to the meaning of an utterance. Besides which ***respective*** is often used to mean ***respectfully***, which is a completely different meaning.

Comment: ...the first two relevant usages I found in Google Books were *representatives shall be chosen every year by the voters in their **respective** districts* and *The comparison of the **respective** merits of cheap and dear labour might end here*. I can't see that anything of significance is lost if the highlighted word is simply removed in each case.

Comment: If you want to use it - "A, B and C drove X, Y and Z respectively."